# Storing and Retrieving from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a music website in which people are able to visit an artist's page, listen to their music, and submit their ratings of the artist using a form with four sliders corresponding to the values (0-100) of the following attributes : Flow, Metaphors, Charisma, and Wordplay. The averages of each attribute is then displayed on the artists page.

The submitted values are entered into a table called 'attributes' of the database 'lr' with the following columns.

```
// The database connection has already been established.



  id(AUTO INCREMENTED)<br>
    userid (Corresponding to the id of the artist who was viewed)<br>
    Flow (INT of 3)
    Metaphors (INT of 3)
    Wordplay (INT of 3) 
    Charisma (INT of 3)
```

My first question is: What is an more concise way I could make use of all the values submitted by the page visitors? Could I average out the values into one row of values to be stored in the table for the each respective userid that changes with every submit rather than a lengthy list of hundreds of values corresponding to one user? If so, how?

If there is an easy way to do that, that might change the dynamic of my second question.

---

Secondly,

On the first part of a series of steps to do to make a list ranking the top artists on the site, I need to retrieve the overall score of all the artists: `Overall Score = ( AVG(Flow)+ AVG(Metaphors) + AVG(Wordplay) + AVG(Charisma) / 4 ).` I have tried the following query to return the overall scores for each userid.

```
"SELECT ((AVG(Wordplay) + AVG(Metaphors) + AVG(Charisma) + AVG(Flow)) / 4 ) FROM attributes GROUP BY userid";
```

When I do this it only gets the array for one userid. What is the proper way I can get the overall rating for every userid?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your data more concise by keeping a running average instead of exact scores submitted by everybody. You only need to add up all the ratings to a running total and then increment your dividing counter by 4 (since there are four ratings).

Then your query would just query for RunningTotal / TotalRatings.

To answer the second part of your question, you need to select the userid along with the average.

```
SELECT userid, ((AVG(Wordplay) + AVG(Metaphors) + AVG(Charisma) + AVG(Flow)) / 4 ) FROM attributes GROUP BY userid
```